# IOS DEEP LINKING - fb-messenger , slack, whatsapp, viber

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking

I want to deep link on the apps listed above.
I can open those apps just fine via openUrl.
However, I want to add text in it for example is slack://open?, 
How do I add text in it? 
When I say text, it is the message that I want to prepopulate.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is dependent on the app you're deep linking to, so you will have to check each app's respective documentation (assuming that there is any) for the app's URL format.

Answer (score -1):

Project - > capabilities > on the associate domain and add the domain link.

IN app delegate add the code as given below.
Make sure associate domain is on in your certificates too.

## pragma Universal Links

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSAenter code hererray *restorableObjects))restorationHandler{

    if ([userActivity.activityType isEqualToString:NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb])
    {
        
    }
    return true;
}
```